# How to move a HaxeFlixel FlxNapeSprite?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, nape

I'm trying to use Nape with HaxeFlixel. Sadly, there's almost no documentation on how to use the `addons.nape` package and I just can't figure out why this code isn't moving the white rectangle (`_test`). (I left out imports for simplicity)

```
class PlayState extends FlxNapeState
{
    var _test = new FlxNapeSprite(16, 16);

    override public function create():Void
    {
        super.create();

        _test.makeGraphic(16, 16);
        _test.body.type = BodyType.KINEMATIC;
        add(_test);
    }

    override public function update():Void
    {
        _test.body.velocity.x = 100;
        super.update();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Directly initializing the `_test` variable leads to the `FlxNapeSprite` constructor call happening in the constructor of your `PlayState`. `create()` is called *after* the state constructor. This can cause crashes and otherwise weird behavior since Flixel does its internal cleanup *between* the constructor call of the new state and `create()` (graphics are disposed, for example, and in this case the Nape `Space` instance doesn't exist yet since it's created in the `super.create()` call).
2. The `FlxNapeSprite` constructor has a `createRectangularBody` argument which defaults to `true` and calls the function of that same name if `true`. Since you're not passing any asset to the constructor, it ends up creating a `Shape` with a width and height of 0. This leads to the following error:

   `Error: Cannot simulate with an invalid Polygon`

   Instead, you'll want to call `createRectangularBody()` manually after `makeGraphic()` to create a `Shape` that matches the graphic's dimensions.

The complete, working code looks like this:

```
package;

import flixel.addons.nape.FlxNapeSprite;
import flixel.addons.nape.FlxNapeState;

class PlayState extends FlxNapeState
{
    override public function create():Void
    {
        super.create();

        var _test = new FlxNapeSprite(16, 16);
        _test.makeGraphic(16, 16);
        _test.createRectangularBody();
        _test.body.velocity.x = 100;
        add(_test);
    }
}
```

Regarding documentation, the [FlxNape demo](http://haxeflixel.com/demos/FlxNape/) is a great resource to learn from.